# New Tab in Selenium Using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to open new tab not window.

->When I didn't use ***Profile*** `Window.Open` Script is working fine it opens the link in new tab. But when I use ***Profile*** the link is opening in new Window.
What to do to open new tab when I'm using profile.

->`browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "t")` is not working. What should I do to open the new tab using keys?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/path/g8or2923.default')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile,executable_path='/path/geckodriver')
browser.get('http://www.google.com')

browser.execute_script("window.open('http://build/')")

browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND+"t")
```

I'm using Mac OS

### Update:

Even tried using actions

```
actions = ActionChains(browser)
tag = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
actions.key_down(Keys.COMMAND).click(tag).send_keys("t").perform()
```

### Second Update:

Its is not Duplicate of that question.

Im saying `window.open` open in new window not in a new tab.  And Even `ActionChains` not working

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: newly opened tabs and windows works in same manner in selenium.

Comment: @cruisepandey When I use profile, New Tab is not opening instead of that new window is opening

Comment: @Andersson Updated Clearly